# reactjs insert in handle variable state update

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm new to `reactjs` and am creating a volume bar.

I update my state with my value and I'd like to enter it in `handleclick () {};` so I take updated state and insert it into my function `setVolume ();`

Is there another way for me to enter my `setstate` into `handleclick ();` ?

```
import React from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-rangeslider'
import 'react-rangeslider/lib/index.css'
import './css/Volume.css'

class VolumeBar extends React.Component 

constructor(props, context) {
super(props, context)
this.state = {
  volume: 0
}
}

handleOnChange = (value) => {
this.setState({
  volume: value
})
}

handleClick(volume) {
 window.DZ.player.setVolume()
  }

render() {
    let { volume } = this.state
    console.log(volume);
return (
    <div className="VolumeBar">
    <Slider value={volume} orientation="horizontal" onChange=  {this.handleClick} />
    </div>
);
}
}

export default VolumeBar
```

Comment: you are never calling your `handleOnChange` method.  You are calling handleClick onChange.  You probably want to change it to `onChange={this.handleOnChange}` and then move the `window.DZ.player.setVolume`call to your `handleOnChange` function.

Comment: handleOnChange  () {
    this.setState({
        volume: value
    })
       window.DZ.player.setVolume(volume)
    }

Need insert in setVolume() mi volume   /  and that's how I get the value I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried like that?

```
<Slider value={volume} orientation="horizontal" onChange=this.handleOnChange} />


handleOnChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
      volume: e.target.value
})
```

To set the current volume?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleOnChange = (value) => {
 this.setState({
   volume: value
 })
 window.DZ.player.setVolume(value)
}
```

thank you i solved it like this.